# Could I add a caption over an existing image using Go?

Tags: go, graphics

If I have font files (for different fonts), is it possible to create a caption over  image using Go?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Pretty much anything is possible, considering that cgo is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [gofont](https://github.com/gonutz/gofont) library for that. See [the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gonutz/gofont) for the minimal interface.

You basically call `gofont.LoadFromFile("font.ttf")` and on the returned `Font` object, you can set the `PixelHeight` and `R/G/B` values to control the draw output.

Call `font.Write()` on the object to render text into your `draw.Image`. It is even possible to center text, using the returned x and y values returned by the function.

The library is pure Go and should work on all platforms.